# Tailwind Grid - different rows have different line height

Tags: grid, tailwind-css

When I use grid in tailwind

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-9 grid-rows-3 my-3 leading-4">
    <div class="col-start-1 col-span-5 row-start-1 flex">
        <p class="flex-shrink-0">Company Name：</p>
        <p>ABCD EFGGGG HIJK LMNOPQRS TUVV WXYZZZ</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-start-6 col-span-full row-start-1">
        Date：2022/05/16
    </div>
    <div class="col-start-1 col-span-5 row-start-2 flex">
        <p class="flex-shrink-0">Contact：</p>
        <p class="break-all">Wenston Black</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-start-6 col-span-full row-start-2">
        Tel：XXXXXXXXXXX
    </div>
    <div class="col-start-1 col-span-5 row-start-3">
        email：XXXXXXXX@gmail.com
    </div>
    <div class="col-start-6 col-span-full row-start-3">
        Fax：xxxxxxxxxxxx
    </div>
</div>
```

The Company Name with short value is OK, but with long value it makes every row height grow up.

- short Company Name
  [image]
- long Company Name
  [image]

I need other rows keep height dense.
How can I do?

I know I can do this with flex, but I really need to use grid here.

Comment: @BouncyBits See below, I think you would love that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grid-rows-3` will apply the property `grid-template-rows: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));`, so the rows will always have the same height.

If a grid item is positioned into a row that is not explicitly sized by grid-template-rows, implicit grid tracks are created to hold it with an "auto" height. So just remove `grid-rows-3` from the first div:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-9 my-3 leading-4">
    <div class="col-start-1 col-span-5 row-start-1 flex">
        <p class="flex-shrink-0">Company Name：</p>
        <p>ABCD EFGGGG HIJK LMNOPQRS TUVV WXYZZZ ABCD EFGGGG HIJK LMNOPQRS TUVV WXYZZZ</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-start-6 col-span-full row-start-1">
        Date：2022/05/16
    </div>
    <div class="col-start-1 col-span-5 row-start-2 flex">
        <p class="flex-shrink-0">Contact：</p>
        <p class="break-all">Wenston Black</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-start-6 col-span-full row-start-2">
        Tel：XXXXXXXXXXX
    </div>
    <div class="col-start-1 col-span-5 row-start-3">
        email：XXXXXXXX@gmail.com
    </div>
    <div class="col-start-6 col-span-full row-start-3">
        Fax：xxxxxxxxxxxx
    </div>
</div>
```

See it in [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/0XiFfhic0K).